# Meta SP.SE new look?

Tags: bug, design

What's up with the new rainbow colors on the Meta page? Is there a reason behind that? StackOverflow or ServerFault metas don't have that. Is this something the mods changed?

Comment: I think the same rainbows appear on the SharePoint SE, just with a different bg color. Additionally, the colors have been there on SE's side for a long time. Maybe unifying the UIs?

Comment: @moe: That's definitely this. You should post that as an answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the same rainbows appear on the SharePoint SE, just with a different background color. Additionally, the colors have been there on SE's side for a long time. Therefore this change is likely just for unifying the layouts of the SP.SE sites.